# Google Maps API - cannot find google place ID for my business

Tags: web-services, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'd like to get the google place id for my business to create a link for my clients to leave reviews.

When I type my business name and address into the place id finder it does not return any results.
https://developers.google.com/places/place-id

The 'google my business' listing has been verified since 5 or 6 days ago.

I have searched this forum but I do not code, I'm the business owner, and I haven't had any luck trying any solutions suggested.

My business on google maps:
https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Lift+PT/@51.5172825,-0.0812451,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x825f785e3a8e3819!8m2!3d51.5172825!4d-0.0812451

Thank you for any help you may be able to give me.

Answer (score 1):

From https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Lift%20PT%20London&key=YOUR_KEY

```
   /* Edited for length */
   "results" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "Andaz Hotel Health Club, 40 Liverpool Street, London EC2M 7QN, United Kingdom",
         "formatted_phone_number" : "07763 713331",
         "name" : "Lift PT",
---->    "place_id" : "ChIJZ6YsibIcdkgRGTiOOl54X4I",
         "types" : [ "health", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?cid=9394359693822801945",
         "user_ratings_total" : 1,
         "vicinity" : "Andaz Hotel Health Club, 40 Liverpool Street, London",
         "website" : "https://liftpt.co.uk/"
      },
```